# discord.errors.HTTPException issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm seem to be running in to a Discord error. I'm currently coding a module to pin messages in a specific channel upon message posted.

The module has been tested and it works well but I'm running in to this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\bot\modules\pinner.py", line 22, in 
on_message
    await self.bot.pin_message(message)


   discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot execute 
action on a system message
```

I'm not sure what this error is telling me. But here is the code I'm working with:

```
class Pinner():
"""Pins messages to a specific channel."""

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot


async def on_message(self, message):
    """Listen for message then pin it"""
    server = message.server
    channelid = '469108626888458241'
    if server:
        if message.channel.id == channelid:
            try:
                await self.bot.pin_message(message)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                print("No permissions to do that!")


def setup(bot):
    """Setup function"""
    to_add = Pinner(bot)
    bot.add_listener(to_add.on_message, 'on_message')
    bot.add_cog(to_add)
```

If anyone can help that'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to pin the system message that appears whenever someone pins a message.

> @User pinned a message to this channel. [See all the pins](http://localhost).

You can check for these by checking [`message.type`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.type) against [`MessageType.pins_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType)

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Listen for message then pin it"""
    server = message.server
    channelid = '469108626888458241'
    if server and message.channel.id == channelid and message.type != discord.MessageType.pins_add:
        try:
            await self.bot.pin_message(message)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            print("No permissions to do that!")
```